# How do I check if a string matched in an ANTLR context?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

This ANTLR4 grammar:

```
/* Parser rules */
statement: A '='? B;
/* Lexer rules */
A: ...
B: ...
```

...matches `A B` and `A = B`.

If I make a visitor:

```
public String visitStatement(StatementContext ctx) {
    ...
}
```

How do I check if the matched content is `A B` or `A = B` (more specifically, whether the `=` was matched or not)? I can do this:

```
ctx.getChild(1).getText().equals("=")
```

but it seems too hacky, and doesn't work if it happens that `B`'s text is "`=`". Is there an accepted way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either give the '=' token a name in your grammar or add a label to the `'='?` in that specific rule.

Naming the token:

```
statement: A '='? B; // You can write EQ? here or leave it as '='?
/* Lexer rules */
EQ: '=';
```

Using a label:

```
statement: A eq='='? B;
```

You can then use `.EQ()` or `.eq` respectively to access the `=` token matched by a given `StatementContext`. If there was no `=`, you'll get `null`. So you can use `ctx.EQ() == null` or `ctx.eq == null` to check whether the `=` was there or not.